# How do I dynamically add tab to tabs?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I am trying to add a new tab to the tabs component with the code below.

When running there is no error reported but no additional tabs are show.
I have tried using both tabs and tabs.__tabsModel as the parent but no additional tabs are show.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    id: mainView
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "news-feed"

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Tabs {
        id: tabs
        anchors.fill: parent

        Component.onCompleted: {
            mainView.initializeDB();
            mainView.saveFeed("BBC News","http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
            mainView.saveFeed("Jono Bacon","http://www.jonobacon.org/?feed=rss2");
            mainView.saveFeed("The Register", "http://www.theregister.co.uk/headlines.atom");
            fillTabs();
        }

        tools: ToolbarActions {
            Action {
                objectName: "action"

                iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("avatar.png")
                text: i18n.tr("Tap me!")

                onTriggered: {
                    label.text = i18n.tr("Toolbar tapped")
                }
            }
        }

        // First tab begins here
        Tab {
            id: tabFrontPage
            objectName: "tabFrontPage"

            title: i18n.tr("Front Page")

            // Tab content begins here
            page: Page {
                Column {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    Label {
                        id: labelFrontPage
                        text: i18n.tr("This will be the front page \n An aggregation of the top stories from each feed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function fillTabs() {
        var db = getDatabase();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM feeds;');
            if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                    var feedTab = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0;import Ubuntu.Components 0.1;Tab {anchors.fill: parent;objectName: "Tab";title: i18n.tr("Tab");page: Page {anchors.margins: units.gu(2);Column {anchors.centerIn: parent;Label {id: label;objectName: "label";text: i18n.tr("Tab");}}}}',tabs,"feedTab");
                }
            } else {
                res = "Unknown";
            }
        })
    }
    //Storage API
    function getDatabase() {
        return LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("news-feed","1.0","StorageDatabase",10000)
    }

    //Initialise DB tables if not already existing
    function initializeDB() {
        var db = getDatabase();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            //Create settings table if not existing
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings(setting TEXT UNIQUE, value TEXT)');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feeds(feedName TEXT UNIQUE, feedURL TEXT UNIQUE)')
        });
    }

    //Write setting to DB
    function setSetting(setting,value){
        //setting: string - setting name (key)
        //value: string - value
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res = "";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (?,?);',[setting,value]);
            //console.log(rs.rowsAffected)
            if(rs.rowsAffected > 0) {
                res = "OK";
            } else {
                res = "Error";
            }
        })
        return res;
    }

    //Read setting from DB
    function getSetting(setting) {
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res="";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting=?;', [setting]);
            if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                res = rs.rows.item(0).value;
            } else {
                res = "Unknown";
            }
        })
        return res;
    }

    function saveFeed(feedName, feedURL) {
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res = "";
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            var rs = tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO feeds VALUES (?,?)',[feedName,feedURL]);
            //console.log(rs.rowsAffected)
            if (rs.rowsAffected > 0) {
                res = "OK";
            } else {
                res = "Error";
            }
        })
        return res;
    }

    //Return a single feed
    function getFeed(feedName) {
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res = "";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT feedURL FROM feeds WHERE feedName=?;', [feedName]);
            if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                res = rs.rows.item(0).feedURL;
            } else {
                res = "Unknown";
            }

        })
        return res;
    }

    //Return all feeds and urls
    function getFeeds() {
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res = "";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM feeds;');
            if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                return rs;
            } else {
                res = "Unknown";
            }
        })
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question may be slightly off topic here. I would recommend for a quicker and better response to ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: The question is totally on topic. We've been using Ask Ubuntu for app development questions quite successfully for quite a while now.

Comment: Also - the issue may specifically relate to the ubuntu-components

Comment: close vote done accidentally , I am sorry Friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that adding tabs dynamically it is currently not possible

The SDK team tell me that this is a limitation of the [VisualItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-visualitemmodel.html) type (which the the [Tabs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components0-tabs.html) component uses), as it does not allow adding children dynamically.

There is an open [bug to keep track of this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1124071).

Comment: still some work ahead ;-)

Comment: is there a ticket one can track?

Comment: I thought as much.
I got around it by creating the whole tabs container component and all contained Tab components in a javascript function and then adding it with mainView as the parent.
Horribly hackey but it works :P

Comment: @payload, there isn't a bug to keep track of this right, now, but please feel free to open one for the SDK team to have a look at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+filebug

Comment: @payload, Someone had already logged a ticket with this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1124071.

My workaround to use Qt.createQmlObject function with the tabs collection and all children can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/dmyPkyyX Its really not very elegant and the string becomes unmanageable quickly but works. See the fillTabs() function.

Comment: @Morchuboo, thanks, I've updated the answer with the bug report. You might want to post your workaround code snippet as an additional answer as well. I'm sure others trying to do the same could benefit from your work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example workaround.

This method results in almost all of the gui being specified in a string and becomes messy quickly but will work until the feature to append to VisualItemModel is implemented upstream.

This is the start of a rss reader I am tinkering with. If you paste it into an empty qml file it should run fine. (you may need to install libqt5sql5-sqlite and qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin. They are on the phone images but were not installed with the SDK install).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

/*!
    \brief MainView with Tabs element.
       First Tab has a single Label and
       second Tab has a single ToolbarAction.
*/

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    id: mainView
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "news-feed"

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    tools: ToolbarActions {
    Action {
        objectName: "action"

        iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("avatar.png")
        text: i18n.tr("Tap me!")

        onTriggered: {
            label.text = i18n.tr("Toolbar tapped")
        }
    }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
    mainView.initializeDB();
    mainView.saveFeed("BBC News","http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
    mainView.saveFeed("Jono Bacon","http://www.jonobacon.org/?feed=rss2");
    mainView.saveFeed("The Register", "http://www.theregister.co.uk/headlines.atom");
    fillTabs();
    }

    Tabs {
    id: initialtabs
    anchors.fill: parent

    tools: ToolbarActions {
        Action {
            objectName: "action"

            iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("avatar.png")
            text: i18n.tr("Tap me!")

            onTriggered: {
                label.text = i18n.tr("Toolbar tapped")
            }
        }
    }

    // First tab begins here
    Tab {
        id: tabFrontPage
        objectName: "tabFrontPage"

        title: i18n.tr("Front Page")

        // Tab content begins here
        page: Page {
            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    id: labelFrontPage
                    text: i18n.tr("This will be the front page \n An aggregation of the top stories from each feed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }


    function fillTabs() {
    initialtabs.destroy();
    var objStr = "import QtQuick 2.0;import Ubuntu.Components 0.1;import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0;Tabs{id:tabs;anchors.fill:parent;"
    var db = getDatabase();
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM feeds;');
        if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                objStr += "Tab {id:tab" + i + ";anchors.fill:parent;title:'" + rs.rows.item(i).feedName + "';property string source: '" + rs.rows.item(i).feedURL + "';page: Page {anchors.margins: units.gu(2);Column {anchors.centerIn: parent;Label{text:tab" + i + ".source;}}}}";
            }
            objStr += "}";
            var cmpTabs = Qt.createQmlObject(objStr,mainView,"tabsfile");
        } else {
            res = "Unknown";
        }
    })
    }

    //Create tabs for each feed
    function createTabs() {
    var feeds = getFeeds();
    for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++){
        //Add tab for each feed.
        //Cannot be done with existing API

    }
    }

    //Storage API
    function getDatabase() {

    return LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("news-feed","1.0","StorageDatabase",10000)
    }

    //Initialise DB tables if not already existing
    function initializeDB() {
    var db = getDatabase();
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        //Create settings table if not existing
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings(setting TEXT UNIQUE, value TEXT)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feeds(feedName TEXT UNIQUE, feedURL TEXT UNIQUE)')
    });
    }

    //Write setting to DB
    function setSetting(setting,value){
    //setting: string - setting name (key)
    //value: string - value
    var db = getDatabase();
    var res = "";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (?,?);',[setting,value]);
        //console.log(rs.rowsAffected)
        if(rs.rowsAffected > 0) {
            res = "OK";
        } else {
            res = "Error";
        }
    })
    return res;
    }

    //Read setting from DB
    function getSetting(setting) {
       var db = getDatabase();
       var res="";
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
     var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting=?;', [setting]);
     if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
          res = rs.rows.item(0).value;
     } else {
         res = "Unknown";
     }
      })
      // The function returns “Unknown” if the setting was not found in the database
      // For more advanced projects, this should probably be handled through error codes
      return res;
    }

    function saveFeed(feedName, feedURL) {
    var db = getDatabase();
    var res = "";
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        var rs = tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO feeds VALUES (?,?)',[feedName,feedURL]);
        //console.log(rs.rowsAffected)
        if (rs.rowsAffected > 0) {
            res = "OK";
        } else {
            res = "Error";
        }
    })
    return res;
    }

    //Return a single feed
    function getFeed(feedName) {
    var db = getDatabase();
    var res = "";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT feedURL FROM feeds WHERE feedName=?;', [feedName]);
        if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
            res = rs.rows.item(0).feedURL;
        } else {
            res = "Unknown";
        }

    })
    return res;
    }

    //Return all feeds and urls
    function getFeeds() {
    var db = getDatabase();
    var res = "";
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM feeds;');
        if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
            return rs;
        } else {
            res = "Unknown";
        }
        })
    return res;
    }
}
```